# When I add users in Ubuntu I get panel errors regarding an applet?

Tags: ubuntu, troubleshooting

I have install Ubuntu & GNOME (with minimum possible number of packages).
I can login and do anything I want. However, there is a strange thing: Whenever I log in, I see this message:

```
Error
The panel encountered a problem while loading "OAFIID:GNOME_FastUserSwitchApplet"
Do you want to delete the applet from your configuration
[Don't Delete] [Delete]
```

If I press [Delete] then the error won't be shown anymore.
However, for every newly created account, the message is shown again (created using `sudo adduser user_name`).

Since I clone this OS into several virtual instance, and create new account on these instances; I wonder if there is a way to configure my Ubuntu so that newly created user doesn't have to see this annoying message?

Answer (score 1):

Via the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=b627bb74ce9694694c2a313a1b7c9e81&p=2069932&postcount=2):

> Please try to reinstall **gnome-applets**
>   and **gnome-applets-data**.

Comment: Hmm, I tried it before and it didn't solve the problem. I tried again and it still doesnot solve the problem. Do you know a way to troubleshoot it? (Like which log to view)

Comment: Can I get some more information; for instance, what applets do you have running on your taskbars?  It sounds like these might be the culprit.

Comment: I install fast-user-switching-applet and the message gone away. Probably ubuntu default configuration assume that this applet must be installed.